# Add and Remove Views in Android Dynamically?

Tags: android, android-view

How do I add and remove views such as `TextView`s from Android app like on the original stock Android contacts screen where you press a small icon on the right side of a field and it adds or deletes a field which consists of a `TextView` and an `editTextView` (from what I can see).

Any examples on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 249, accepted):

`ViewParent`s in general can't remove views, but `ViewGroup`s can. You need to cast your parent to a `ViewGroup` (if it is a `ViewGroup`) to accomplish what you want.

For example:

```
View namebar = View.findViewById(R.id.namebar);
((ViewGroup) namebar.getParent()).removeView(namebar);
```

Note that all `Layout`s are `ViewGroup`s.

Comment: ViewParent can't remove a subview, but ViewGroup can.

Comment: The link is broken. Avoid relate the whole answer to a external link, as seen on this meta question:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: I have a similar type of problem can you pl see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73306074/6854117)?

Answer (score 39):

I need the exact same feature described in this question. Here is my solution and source code: https://github.com/laoyang/android-dynamic-views. And you can see the video demo in action here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HeqyG6FDhQ

### Layout

Basically you'll two xml layout files:

- A horizontal LinearLayout **row view** with a `TextEdit`, a `Spinner` and an `ImageButton` for deletion.
- A vertical LinearLayout **container view** with just a **Add new** button.

### Control

In the Java code, you'll add and remove row views into the container dynamically, using inflate, addView, removeView, etc. There are some visibility control for better UX in the stock Android app. You need add a TextWatcher for the EditText view in each row: when the text is empty you need to hide the **Add new** button and the delete button. In my code, I wrote a `void inflateEditRow(String)` helper function for all the logic.

### Other tricks

- Set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in xml to enable animation
- Use custom transparent background with **pressed** selector to make the buttons visually the same as the ones in the stock Android app.

### Source code

The Java code of the main activity ( This explains all the logic, but quite a few properties are set in xml layout files, please refer to the Github source for complete solution):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Parent view for all rows and the add button.
private LinearLayout mContainerView;
// The "Add new" button
private Button mAddButton;
// There always should be only one empty row, other empty rows will
// be removed.
private View mExclusiveEmptyView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.row_container);
    mContainerView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentView);
    mAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewItem);

    // Add some examples
    inflateEditRow("Xiaochao");
    inflateEditRow("Yang");
}

// onClick handler for the "Add new" button;
public void onAddNewClicked(View v) {
    // Inflate a new row and hide the button self.
    inflateEditRow(null);
    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

// onClick handler for the "X" button of each row
public void onDeleteClicked(View v) {
    // remove the row by calling the getParent on button
    mContainerView.removeView((View) v.getParent());
}

// Helper for inflating a row
private void inflateEditRow(String name) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    final ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.editText);
    if (name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
        editText.setText(name);
    } else {
        mExclusiveEmptyView = rowView;
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    // A TextWatcher to control the visibility of the "Add new" button and
    // handle the exclusive empty view.
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // Some visibility logic control here:
            if (s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                mAddButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                deleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                if (mExclusiveEmptyView != null
                        && mExclusiveEmptyView != rowView) {
                    mContainerView.removeView(mExclusiveEmptyView);
                }
                mExclusiveEmptyView = rowView;
            } else {
                if (mExclusiveEmptyView == rowView) {
                    mExclusiveEmptyView = null;
                }
                mAddButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }
    });

    // Inflate at the end of all rows but before the "Add new" button
    mContainerView.addView(rowView, mContainerView.getChildCount() - 1);
}
```

Comment: was working on something similar to this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679833/how-to-check-which-editext-textwatcher-listener-is-called-in-dynamically-created) this works well

Comment: As per my screen height, i can add 7 entries, after that "Add New" button is not visible, its hidden below softKeyboard. to click "Add New" i have to hide keyboard and click button "Add New" to add more entries. After 12 entries "Add New" Button is buried below screen,
![Valid XHTML](http://postimg.org/image/qilfb8oj9/).

Comment: I have a similar type of problem can you pl see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73306074/6854117)?

Answer (score 12):

This is my general way:

```
View namebar = view.findViewById(R.id.namebar);
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) namebar.getParent();
if (parent != null) {
    parent.removeView(namebar);
}
```

Comment: I have a similar type of problem can you pl see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73306074/6854117)?

Answer (score 6):

Hi You can try this way by adding relative layout and than add textview in that.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

RelativeLayout relative = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
relative.setLayoutParams(lp);

TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

EditText edittv = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
edittv.setLayoutParams(lp);

relative.addView(tv);
relative.addView(edittv);
```

Comment: Will that autamtically add a new view to the layout without reloading the whole screen? much like how u add a new textfield in contacts?

Comment: Android has to redraw the screen when you add a new view (I think). But it shouldn't affect you in most cases

Comment: Any examples on how to remove a specific view from a linearLayout?

Comment: Down voted due to not including example of how to remove a view.

Comment: down voted for not implementing a remove view method

Comment: For removing views from a LinearLayout this is what I do. MyLinearLayoutThatHoldsOtherViews.removeAllViews(); removeAllViews() is the key. Hope it helps and makes sense. ^.^

Comment: I have a similar type of problem can you pl see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73306074/6854117)?

Answer (score 5):

Just use `myView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` to remove it completely.
But if you want to reserve the occupied space inside its parent use `myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: It's not removing just hiding.

Comment: yes but View.GONE is completely like removing because the reserved space not shows anymore.

Comment: Excellent post, sorted out my problem. I believe this is the correct answer if your views have already been created in xml and you simply want to show or hide them and let other views take up the space where those hidden views should be.

Comment: Do remember that `View.INVISIBLE` only hides the view. The `OnClickListener` (if set) will still respond to the user if they touch the _area_ where the view is present (but not visible). So you should ideally also remove `OnClickListeners` in such cases

Comment: I have a similar type of problem can you pl see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73306074/6854117)?

Answer (score 5):

### Kotlin Extension Solution

Add `removeSelf` to directly call on a view. If attached to a parent, it will be removed. This makes your code more declarative, and thus readable.

```
myView.removeSelf()

fun View?.removeSelf() {
    this ?: return
    val parent = parent as? ViewGroup ?: return
    parent.removeView(this)
}
```

Here are 3 options for how to programmatically add a view to a `ViewGroup`.

```
// Built-in
myViewGroup.addView(myView)

// Reverse addition
myView.addTo(myViewGroup)

fun View?.addTo(parent: ViewGroup?) {
    this ?: return
    parent ?: return
    parent.addView(this)
}

// Null-safe extension
fun ViewGroup?.addView(view: View?) {
    this ?: return
    view ?: return
    addView(view)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) class provides API for child views management in run-time, allowing  to add/remove views as well.

Some other links on the subject:

[Android, add new view without XML Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211559/android-add-new-view-without-xml-layout)

[Android Runtime Layout Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693744/android-runtime-layout-tutorial)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Comment: ViewGroup nor its methods provide an API (which is instead a set of libraries), but just some method to handle the behaviors (such as adding and removing views) you say. And those methods aren't just a thing to manage views at runtime, but the unique way to manage them. When you write an XML layout, it is just parsed in Java and views are created based on it during the run-time!

Answer (score 3):

For Adding the Button

```
LinearLayout dynamicview = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams  lprams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setId(count);
final int id_ = btn.getId();
btn.setText("Capture Image" + id_);
btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(70, 80, 90));
dynamicview.addView(btn, lprams);
btn = ((Button) findViewById(id_));
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

For removing the button

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
View command = layout.findViewById(count);
layout.removeView(command);
```

Comment: count is nothing but the id of the button created dynamically

Answer (score 3):

Hi First write the Activity class. The following class have a Name of category and small add button. When you press on add (+) button it adds the new row which contains an EditText and an ImageButton which performs the delete of the row.

```
package com.blmsr.manager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.blmsr.manager.R;
import com.blmsr.manager.dao.CategoryService;
import com.blmsr.manager.models.CategoryModel;
import com.blmsr.manager.service.DatabaseService;

public class CategoryEditorActivity extends Activity {
    private final String CLASSNAME = "CategoryEditorActivity";
    LinearLayout itsLinearLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_editor);

        itsLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_category_editor, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_delete:
            deleteCategory();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_save:
            saveCategory();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * Adds a new row which contains the EditText and a delete button.
 * @param theView
 */
public void addField(View theView)
{
    itsLinearLayout.addView(tableLayout(), itsLinearLayout.getChildCount()-1);
}

// Using a TableLayout as it provides you with a neat ordering structure

private TableLayout tableLayout() {
    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tableLayout.addView(createRowView());
    return tableLayout;
}

private TableRow createRowView() {
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    tableRow.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);

    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setWidth(600);
    editText.requestFocus();

    tableRow.addView(editText);
    ImageButton btnGreen = new ImageButton(this);
    btnGreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete);
    btnGreen.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    btnGreen.setOnClickListener(anImageButtonListener);
    tableRow.addView(btnGreen);

    return tableRow;
}

/**
 * Delete the row when clicked on the remove button.
 */
private View.OnClickListener anImageButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TableRow anTableRow = (TableRow)v.getParent();
        TableLayout anTable = (TableLayout) anTableRow.getParent();
        itsLinearLayout.removeView(anTable);

    }
};

/**
 * Save the values to db.
 */
private void saveCategory()
{
    CategoryService aCategoryService = DatabaseService.getInstance(this).getCategoryService();
    aCategoryService.save(getModel());
    Log.d(CLASSNAME, "successfully saved model");

    Intent anIntent = new Intent(this, CategoriesListActivity.class);
    startActivity(anIntent);

}

/**
 * performs the delete.
 */
private void deleteCategory()
{

}

/**
 * Returns the model object. It gets the values from the EditText views and sets to the model.
 * @return
 */
private CategoryModel getModel()
{
    CategoryModel aCategoryModel = new CategoryModel();
    try
    {
        EditText anCategoryNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.categoryNameEditText);
        aCategoryModel.setCategoryName(anCategoryNameEditText.getText().toString());
        for(int i= 0; i< itsLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            View aTableLayOutView = itsLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if(aTableLayOutView instanceof  TableLayout)
            {
                for(int j= 0; j< ((TableLayout) aTableLayOutView).getChildCount() ; j++ );
                {
                    TableRow anTableRow = (TableRow) ((TableLayout) aTableLayOutView).getChildAt(i);
                    EditText anEditText =  (EditText) anTableRow.getChildAt(0);
                    if(StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(anEditText.getText().toString()))
                    {
                        // show a validation message.
                        //return aCategoryModel;
                    }

                    setValuesToModel(aCategoryModel, i + 1, anEditText.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception anException)
    {
        Log.d(CLASSNAME, "Exception occured"+anException);
    }

    return aCategoryModel;
}

/**
 * Sets the value to model.
 * @param theModel
 * @param theFieldIndexNumber
 * @param theFieldValue
 */
private void setValuesToModel(CategoryModel theModel, int theFieldIndexNumber, String theFieldValue)
{
    switch (theFieldIndexNumber)
    {
        case 1 :
            theModel.setField1(theFieldValue);
            break;
        case 2 :
            theModel.setField2(theFieldValue);
            break;
        case 3 :
            theModel.setField3(theFieldValue);
            break;
        case 4 :
            theModel.setField4(theFieldValue);
            break;
        case 5 :
            theModel.setField5(theFieldValue);
            break;
        case 6 :
            theModel.setField6(theFieldValue);
            break;
        case 7 :
            theModel.setField7(theFieldValue);
            break;
        case 8 :
            theModel.setField8(theFieldValue);
            break;
        case 9 :
            theModel.setField9(theFieldValue);
            break;
        case 10 :
            theModel.setField10(theFieldValue);
            break;
        case 11 :
            theModel.setField11(theFieldValue);
            break;
        case 12 :
            theModel.setField12(theFieldValue);
            break;
        case 13 :
            theModel.setField13(theFieldValue);
            break;
        case 14 :
            theModel.setField14(theFieldValue);
            break;
        case 15 :
            theModel.setField15(theFieldValue);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

**2. Write the Layout xml as given below.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#006699"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.blmsr.manager.CategoryEditorActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/addCategiryNameItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_category_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryIconName"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_category_icon_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/categoryNameEditText"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/lbl_category_name"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addField"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/addCategoryLayout"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_input_add"
                android:onClick="addField"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

3. Once you finished your view will as shown below
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
//MainActivity :





 package com.edittext.demo;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private EditText edtText;
        private LinearLayout LinearMain;
        private Button btnAdd, btnClear;
        private int no;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            edtText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtMain);
            btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
            btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
            LinearMain = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearMain);

            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(edtText.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        no = Integer.parseInt(edtText.getText().toString());
                        CreateEdittext();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please entere value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LinearMain.removeAllViews();
                    edtText.setText("");
                }
            });

            /*edtText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });*/

        }

        protected void CreateEdittext() {
            final EditText[] text = new EditText[no];
            final Button[] add = new Button[no];
            final LinearLayout[] LinearChild = new LinearLayout[no];
            LinearMain.removeAllViews();

            for (int i = 0; i < no; i++){

                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edit_text, LinearMain,false);
                text[i] = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edtText);
                text[i].setId(i);
                text[i].setTag(""+i);

                add[i] = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
                add[i].setId(i);
                add[i].setTag(""+i);

                LinearChild[i] = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.child_linear);
                LinearChild[i].setId(i);
                LinearChild[i].setTag(""+i);

                LinearMain.addView(view);

                add[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "add text "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        int a = Integer.parseInt(text[v.getId()].getText().toString());
                        LinearChild[v.getId()].removeAllViews();
                        for (int k = 0; k < a; k++){

                            EditText text = (EditText) new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                            text.setId(k);
                            text.setTag(""+k);

                            LinearChild[v.getId()].addView(text);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

// Now add xml main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtMain"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter value" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Clear" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

//  now add view xml file..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Add" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/child_linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```