# Adding multiple views to a view

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, viewflipper

I want to add a view comprising of 4 buttons and a textview to a linear layout and set that newly made view to a viewflipper...Client's requirement is that i need to create the layout the programmatically and not using an xml file

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view

Comment: I want to add a view comprising of 4 buttons and a textview to a linear layout and set that newly made view to a viewflipper...Client's requirement is that i need to create the layout the programmatically and not using an xml file

Comment: Your client doesn't know what they're talking about and it's your job to advise them on the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this is sample code, this might helpful for you. Instaed of LockView you can mention other views..

```
  lockLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.quick_lock_layout);


   private void renderLockLayout() {
        lockLayout.removeAllViews();
        lockLayout.invalidate();



        lockLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                lockLayoutWidth + 7, (height / 6)));
        /*
         * Toast.makeText(ApplicationContext.getContext(), "Num count is :" +
         * _totalLocks, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         */
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Total :" + _totalLocks);
        lockViewArray = new LockView[_totalLocks];
        for (int index = 0; index < _totalLocks; index++) {
            LockView lockview = (LockView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.lockview,
                    null);
            lockview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((width),
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            lockLayout.addView(lockview);
            lockViewArray[index] = lockview;
        }
        lockLayout.invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: I agree with simon...n yeaah Thanx Sandeep !

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to define UI in XMl. But for your client requirement you can do it dynamically. In android, UI in xml and at run time (.java file) are optional each other.
So use java methods to create LinearLayout and add newly created views to it. Finally you can add this LinearLayout to ViewFlipper.

Comment: Thats what I am asking how do i add this newly created view to the layout !