# How to implement non-scrollable listview in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm designing an activity for my android application.
I want to show the user some items(items are in an ArrayList).

I've done it using ListView but I want the whole activity to be scrollable not the ListView. I wanted to post image here to show what I want to do but I'm new here so I can't!
but here is something like that:

http://upload7.ir/images/69088559301910500020.png

Comment: what happend if data is too large?

Comment: How about use ListView w/ some headers or footer. Check the document. [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView)

Comment: @Chansuk it seems like to work. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LinearLayout` or whatever layout you're using for your `Activity` and put it inside a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Can I use the ArrayAdaptor in this way?
You mean I should insatiate the elements in java code using a loop and inflater?

Comment: You mean for the elements in the layout?

Comment: I've got some object in an arraylist and I want to show them.
I mean each row of the list.

Comment: If you want it to NOT be scrollable and display them dynamically you can add them to the layout. Check out this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view