# android - add/remove views dynamically: Activities vs Fragments

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-view

I want to ask which is best approach to add e.g  or  using  to the screen? Should I use the method described here [Android - Dynamically Add Views into View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view) (i think its for Activity) or should I use fragment in app.

I'm making an simple CGPA calculator app. I want to add another  in  for another subject/course if user presses "Button" marked with "+". I hope you got the idea.

I just want to know which is best way to do it.
I'm very beginner , ignore if you find this question stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I want to add another in for another subject/course if user presses "Button" marked with "+".
```

**Fragments** will be in favor here based on your question. So when each time you click the button you just `add` next fragment to the activity layout, make sure that you dont use the replace method of the `fragment manager` that it will replace the layout of the activity_main use the add method instead. You can [follow this thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) on how to add fragment to the activity.