# Generate duplicate row using onclick button

Tags: android, button

I want to create `editText` and `button` on my project, when click on the button it duplicate the same row. Example

```
My Hobby
----------
Badminton   +
```

When click on the + button there will be a new row generate and the new row include with - to delete this row, only the first row not - button. I need to keep the data that from the edittext and save it to my database.

```
My Hobby
  ----------
   Badminton   +
 - Basketball  +
```

Is this possible way to create? Or any suggestion to create this?

Comment: Simply create row dynamically

Comment: I have no idea to how to create row dynamic, can you send me some link or code to show me?thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fairly easily.  First, create an xml file that holds the views you'd want for the row.  Then in the onClick of the + key, inflate that file into a view, and add it to the parent layout.  Remember to set any fields you need to like onClickListeners or view texts.  On a minus click, remove the view you inflated from its parent.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it, I found a post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view,but I dont know how to apply in my project, can you write a simple code to show me, thanks