# Make a dynamic interface on android app

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-edittext

After a hard job of research to see if i could find the solution to my problem, i decided to ask here.

Well, my problem is I want to make an interface where the fields appear dynamically as in google contacts after enter data, i want that when i press a button after entering some data to show a new edittext to enter more data.

I left you a picture of the screen of the google app to better understanding the problem
[image: google contacts example]

In google app after entering a phone for example, a EditText appears below along with a spinner, I want to imitate this behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view). You just need to add views to the current layout. If you'd like more than that, please start writing some sample code and post issues you come up with instead.