# Best way to display large amount of text in an Android App

Tags: android, html, webview, textview

I'm relatively new to mobile app development - I'm kinda learning as I go.  I'm creating an app that will serve multiple purposes - notifications, audio/video, etc.  One of the features of the app will be to display the contents of an unpublished book (no plans to publish it either via the traditional methods available today).  Essentially, I want the part of the app to do teh following:

1)  Have a menu which will server as a table of contents.
2)  Display the text, which will be in English and Arabic.
3)  Have the english text searchable.
4)  Have the ability to favorite certain sections of the text.

Just wondering what's the best way to build this?  Should I convert sections of my file to html and use webview?  Or should I use textview?

I'm looking for the option that gives me the most robustness in terms of functionality, and flexibility when it comes to design (i.e. background images, custom fonts, formatting).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was your solution buddy ?

Answer (score 0):

WebView or HTML page is not a very good approach.

You can try an approach in which your data is stored in json format in your resources-->raw folder and then parse each element of the JsonObject to populate views dynamically.(If you have server then you fetch data via HttpConnection). For start you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view)

Answer (score -1):

convert your file to html file and display it using webview container...If you have your book in word format then convert it to html file in any website and then display it using webview.