# how to draw/design the screen using code in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am building an app for android in eclipse and don't know the exact no. of textfield it will require as it depends the user how much times the users click add row.in Eclipse you get the graphical tools(i.e. drag and drop) to design you app's view which is done before coding.I want to design my app and add/remove labels,textfield through coding and alter it through coding.

Comment: listview is the way to go . Use textfield in listview

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view programmatically like this:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

Then just add it to the layout. You can find more information here:
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-programmatically-generate.html

Comment: how do i set its location on the screen i.e. where it will appear

Comment: You should take a look at layouts in android:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html