# ListView or LinearLayout - creating Buttons dynamically

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout, android-arrayadapter

When a user enters a word, it creates `Buttons` - one `Button` per letter of the word:

Illustration:

[image]

If the user enters "so" it creates 2 `Buttons` - 's', 'o'

If the user enters "make"  it creates 4 `Buttons` - 'm', 'a', 'k', 'e'

I was having a hard time deciding how I should design this. Ultimately I decided to do the following: Each word is added to a vertical `LinearLayout`. And for each word, each letter is added to a horizontal `LinearLayout`. So it's a `LinearLayout` within a `LinearLayout` approach.

Here's the code I created which works:

```
     //creates words dynamically
     public void makeNewWord(LinearLayout ll, View v, EditText e){

        //the horizontal linear layout
        LinearLayout linearLayout2 = new LinearLayout(v.getContext());
        linearLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        //the parameters for the horizontal linear layout                  
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);    

        //e is the user input 
        int size = e.getText().toString().length();

        for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
             final Button dynamicButtons = new Button(v.getContext());
             dynamicButtons.setLayoutParams(rlp);

             //add the buttons to the horizontal linear layout 
             linearLayout2.addView(dynamicButtons, rlp);  
        }

        // ll is the vertical linear layout which I created in xml
        // so for each entered word, I am adding horizontal linear layouts to my vertical layout
        ll.addView(linearLayout2, 0);
    }
```

But now I realized it's probably more efficient using a `ListView`, especially since I want to make the list of words to be expandable and collapsible. But Is it possible to create the above illustration using a `ListView`? How would I go about doing so?

I tried creating an `ArrayAdapter` as follows: `ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout>(this, R.id.listview)`. So basically it would be a `ListView` of horizontal `LinearLayouts`. Or should I make an `ArrayAdapter` of `Buttons` instead? What is the correct approach?

Comment: I think the simple answer is no. You can't so that with a list view, because once you write a custom adapter you need to have a list item view for it to take as a parameter. That list item view is static - usually done with an XML file. I think it would be much easier to just implement a way of making the screen scroll manually with what you have - which is really not that difficult at all!

Comment: Scrollable is easy. But I want my list of words to be collapsible and expandable too. And I heard it's possible to create an expandable ListView. -- I edited the above post to not include the comment about scrolling. I left in the part about expanding and collapsing since that is the most important part

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TableLayout for this.

test.xml

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Activity Code

```
private TableLayout tableLayout;
private HashMap<String, TableRow> tableRows;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
    tableRows = new HashMap<String, TableRow>();
}

public void addWord(String word) {
    if (!tableRows.containsKey(word)) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            String letter = String.valueOf(word.charAt(i));

            Button btnLetter = new Button(this);
            btnLetter.setText(letter);
            tableRow.addView(btnLetter);
        }

        tableRows.put(word, tableRow);
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
}

public void removeWord(String word) {
    TableRow tableRow = tableRows.remove(word);

    if (tableRow != null) {
        tableLayout.removeView(tableRow);
    }
}

public void showWord(String word) {
    TableRow tableRow = tableRows.get(word);

    if (tableRow != null) {
        tableRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void hideWord(String word) {
    TableRow tableRow = tableRows.get(word);

    if (tableRow != null) {
        tableRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Assuming you want a specific button setup, you can inflate an xml button layout dynamically. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I can give some idea you can transform this idea in code

```
     1. onTextChanged() method try to get length of text.
     2. If you able to get text length then by subString() method get last entered text
     3. Then recreate new button instance
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a horizontal list view per word.
I you want to be fancy you create a custom layout manager and the new RecyclerView.

Each character of your word would be then a item in your list view. The layout then could be simply a button.

```
class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context fContext;
    private String mWord;

    public ListAdapter(Context context) {
        fContext = context;

    }

    public void updateWord(String word) {
        mWord = word;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mWord == null ? 0 : mWord.length();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return String.valueOf(mWord.charAt(position));
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button button;
        if (convertView == null) {
            button = new Button(parent.getContext());

            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            button.setLayoutParams(params);
        } else {
            button = (Button) convertView;
        }
        button.setText(getItem(position));
        return button;
    }
}
```

On every text change you can then just update the list.

```
adapter.updateWord();
```

Be aware the code is just out of my head and i haven't tested this, but should be enough to give you and idea.