# Android: How to dynamically add a "Custom View" into a linear layout

Tags: android, custom-view

I am a newer on building up Android application. 
I want to add a new "custom view", which is composed of buttons and imageView, when i click the button in the MainActivity. 
I have followed some of the website list below to build a custom view.

[javatechig](http://javatechig.com/android/creating-custom-views-in-android-tutorial)
[developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

They work perfect. However, if i want to dynamically add a custom view with

```
 sView sview = new sView(MainActivity.this);
```

nothing happen later on...

Or if I want to new a custom view by

```
sView sview = new sView(MainActivity.this, attrs);
```

Where can i find and set the attrs????

Here is my Code,
in the MainActivity,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDraw = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myDraw);
    btnAddRect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    mfView = (sView) findViewById(R.id.draw);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {       

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SingleFingerView sFingerView = new sView(MainActivity.this);
            myDraw.addView(sFingerView);
        }
    });
}
```

in the Custom View,

```
public class sView extends LinearLayout{

public sView(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
}

public sView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public sView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this._1dp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    this.parseAttr(context, attrs);
    View mRoot = View.inflate(context, R.layout.test_image_view, null);
    addView(mRoot, -1, -1);
    mView = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.view);
    mPushView = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.pview);
    mFirmView = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.fview);
    mRemoveView = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.rview);
}

private void parseAttr(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {    
if (attrs == null)  return;
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.sView);
    if (a != null) {
        int n = a.getIndexCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int attr = a.getIndex(i);

            if (attr == R.styleable.sView_centerInParent) {
                this.mCenterInParent = a.getBoolean(attr, true);
            }  ...
              with some attributes set setting
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setParamsForView(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec); // some params are set here
}
```

and the xml file 
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:pushtouch="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_touch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="abc"
    android:singleLine="false" 
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="ADD IMAGE" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/myDraw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.example.sView
        android:id="@+id/draw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        pushtouch:centerInParent="true"

        pushtouch:image="@drawable/image"
        pushtouch:image_width="120dp"
        pushtouch:image_height="100dp"

        pushtouch:push_image="@drawable/p_btn"
        pushtouch:push_image_width="50dp"
        pushtouch:push_image_height="50dp"

        pushtouch:firm_image="@drawable/ok"
        pushtouch:firm_image_width="50dp"
        pushtouch:firm_image_height="50dp"

        pushtouch:remove_image="@drawable/remove"
        pushtouch:remove_image_width="50dp"
        pushtouch:remove_image_height="50dp"

        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/result"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/result"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/result"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/result"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and corresponding view t_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/drawLayout"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/push_view"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        />
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/firm_view"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        />
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/remove_view"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Use the [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to create a view based on your layout
> template, and then inject it into the view where you need it.
>
> ```
> LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
> View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
>
> // fill in any details dynamically here
> TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.a_text_view);
> textView.setText("your text");
>
> // insert into main view
> ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.insert_point);
> insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
> ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
> ```
>
> You may have to adjust the index where you want to insert the view.

Source : [Android - Dynamically Add Views into View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view)

Comment: GREAT answer for the question! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

u can add some getter and setter function. attrs used in xml.or u can do like this:

```
 test.xml
<com.example.sView
    android:id="@+id/draw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    pushtouch:centerInParent="true"

    pushtouch:image="@drawable/image"
    pushtouch:image_width="120dp"
    pushtouch:image_height="100dp"

    pushtouch:push_image="@drawable/p_btn"
    pushtouch:push_image_width="50dp"
    pushtouch:push_image_height="50dp"

    pushtouch:firm_image="@drawable/ok"
    pushtouch:firm_image_width="50dp"
    pushtouch:firm_image_height="50dp"

    pushtouch:remove_image="@drawable/remove"
    pushtouch:remove_image_width="50dp"
    pushtouch:remove_image_height="50dp"

    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/result"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/result"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/result"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/result"
    />
  onclick -> {
      View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.a,null);
      myDraw.addView(sFingerView);
  }
```

Comment: can you describe your method in details?