# Android Add Buttons to ViewGroup Programmatically

Tags: java, android, viewgroup

I have a ViewGroup.  In this ViewGroup I would like to add three buttons that take up the whole size of the ViewGroup, each evenly taking up the same amount of space.

Where do I add these buttons?  I've tried doing it in the constructor, in onDraw, in onLayout, and none of them seem to display anything.

Comment: ViewGroup has a .addView() method

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view

Comment: addView() isn't doing it unfortunately.  I believe it has something to do with calling .layout on the view, inside of OnLayout, but I'm not sure how to get it to evenly space.

Answer (score 1):

First you should create a button.

```
Button button = new Button (this);
//And you want to set some properties of the view
button.setLayoutParams (new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (....));//Here you should use the corresponding layout params for different ViewGroups, here I used RelativeLayout.
//Maybe you want to set other properties...

ViewGroup viewGroup = //Here get your view group
viewGroup.addView (button);
```

And that's it! The most important part is setting the layout params. **Remember to use the right params or an exception will be thrown**.

Comment: Should the button be created in my MainActivity or inside the ViewGroup that I want it to be placed in?  It seems like it is unorganized to create it in the MainActivity.

Comment: You should use my code in an `Activity` class. I think it is not unorganized if you put it in another method for this specific purpose @theostorm

Comment: You can add the code in other classes too. But you need a `Context` instance to create the button. If you are creating this in a ViewGroup, there should be a getContext method there. @theostorm