# How to get dynamic layout/fields on click of a button in android

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

In my android project I have used three edittext's and four buttons in activity_investments.xml.
 In activity_investments if i press Add fields button,the whole layout i mean three edittext with four button should display again below
  the previous layout..i dont know how to do that.

please help me to get this..

Below is my code..any help would be appreciated...thanks in advance..

**Investments.java**

```
package com.example.miisky;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.graphics.Color;
   import android.graphics.Typeface;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.text.SpannableString;
   import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
   import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
   import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.CheckBox;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.TextView.BufferType;

   public class Investments extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_investments);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);



        Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
        TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        txt1.setTypeface(font1);

        Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
        TextView txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        txt2.setTypeface(font2);

        Typeface font3 = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
        TextView txt3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        txt3.setTypeface(font3);

        Typeface font4 = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
        TextView txt4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
        txt4.setTypeface(font4);

        Typeface font5 = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
        TextView txt5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
        txt5.setTypeface(font5);

        txt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        txt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.twitter.com"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        txt3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.linkedin.com"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        txt4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.googleplus.com"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        txt5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.skype.com"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.investments, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
```

**activity_investments.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/miilogo" />
    </LinearLayout>

   <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/header" >

   <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/root_layout" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Investments"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/panelInvest"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/panelInvest1"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/mutual"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.81"
                    android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:hint="Mutual funds" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/panelInvest2"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/houseprop" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.81"
                android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
                android:ems="10"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:hint="House Property"  />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelInvest3"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/shares" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.81"
                android:background="@drawable/verifyedit"
                android:ems="10"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:hint="Shares"  />

        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelInvest5"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="#042a36"
                android:text="Save"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelInvest6"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="#042a36"
                android:text="Save and Continue"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

           </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelInvest7"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="#042a36"
                android:text="Edit"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

           </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelInvest8"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="#042a36"
                android:text="Add Fields"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

           </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/foot"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:background="#1a292e"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:paddingBottom="0dp"
         android:paddingLeft="0dp"
         android:paddingRight="0dp" >

          <TextView
             android:id="@+id/txtview"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:paddingLeft="110dp"
             android:paddingTop="5dp"
             android:text="FOOTER"
             android:textColor="#006064"
             android:textSize="30dp" />

       </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/header1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:background="#042a36"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                 android:paddingLeft="22dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dip">

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview22"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
                android:paddingRight="22dp"
                 android:text="@string/Copyright"
                 android:textColor="#fff" />

               </LinearLayout>

                 <LinearLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/header2"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="#042a36"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                   >

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/header1"
                android:text="@string/fb1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
                android:textSize="23dp"/>

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/header1"
                    android:text="@string/twitter"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
                    android:textSize="23dp"/>

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/header1"
                    android:text="@string/linkedin1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
                    android:textSize="23dp"/>

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                    android:layout_width="22dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/header1"
                    android:text="@string/googleplus"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
                    android:textSize="23dp"/>


                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/header1"
                     android:text="@string/skype"
                     android:clickable="true"
                    android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
                    android:textSize="23dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

See image below...
[image]

Comment: Just google it, many tutorials are available.
[Possible duplicate.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view)

Comment: in many tutorials only a single field is displayed..but here in my case i want a whole layout should display  after a button click

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/05/add-and-remove-view-dynamically.html  see this

Comment: thanks man..it works..

Answer (score 0):

you can create and add like below

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
 EditText etDateF,etDateT,etLocation,etFormNo,etVIN,etEngine,etName;
     Button btSearch;
     LinearLayout liBottom;
     static int iState = 0; // 1=complaint;2=failure 
     String[][] saData = null;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        methods = new gtCommanMethods(this);
        tableMaster = new TableMaster(this);

        Display  display= ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        bConstants.SCR_WIDTH = display.getWidth(); 
        bConstants.SCR_HEIGHT = display.getHeight();

        LinearLayout liMain = new LinearLayout(this);
        liMain.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        liMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        etDateF = new EditText(this);
        etDateT = new EditText(this);
        etLocation = new EditText(this);
        etFormNo = new EditText(this);
        etVIN = new EditText(this);
        etEngine = new EditText(this);
        etName = new EditText(this);

        etDateF.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        etDateT.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        etLocation.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        etFormNo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        etVIN.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        etEngine.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        etName.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        String search = getResources().getString(R.string.search);
        btSearch = new Button(this);
        btSearch.setText(search);
        btSearch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_patch);



        LinearLayout li1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        li1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        li1.addView(new custText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.from_date)));
        li1.addView(etDateF);
        li1.addView(new custText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.to_date)));
        li1.addView(etDateT);

        LinearLayout li3 = new LinearLayout(this);
        li3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        li3.addView(new custText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.location)));
        li3.addView(etLocation);

        if(iState == 1)
            li3.addView(new custText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.complaint_no)));
        else if(iState == 2)
            li3.addView(new custText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.failure_no)));

        li3.addView(etFormNo);

        LinearLayout li5 = new LinearLayout(this);
        li5.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        li5.addView(new custText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.vin)));
        li5.addView(etVIN);
        li5.addView(new custText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.eng_no)));
        li5.addView(etEngine);

        LinearLayout li7 = new LinearLayout(this);
        li7.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        li7.addView(new custText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.name)));
        li7.addView(etName);
        li7.addView(btSearch);

        LinearLayout liUpper = new LinearLayout(this);
        liUpper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        liUpper.addView(li1);
        liUpper.addView(li3);
        liUpper.addView(li5);
        liUpper.addView(li7);

        liBottom = new LinearLayout(this);
        liBottom.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout liTableHeader = new LinearLayout(this);
        liTableHeader.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        liTableHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        liTableHeader.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);


        liTableHeader.addView(new custText(this,getResources().getString(R.string.name),true),new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(bConstants.SCR_WIDTH/3, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        liTableHeader.addView(new custText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.phone_no),true),new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(bConstants.SCR_WIDTH/3, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        liTableHeader.addView(new custText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.frame_vin_no),true),new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(bConstants.SCR_WIDTH/3, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        liMain.addView(liUpper,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        liMain.addView(liTableHeader,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        liMain.addView(liBottom,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setContentView(liMain);}
```