# Dynamically loaded ImageView not getting layout_height and layout_width specified in xml file

Tags: android, imageview

When i dynamically add ImageView from dynamic_image_view.xml file into linear layout of activity_main.xml, ImageView's layout_height and layout_width are not set according to ImageView in dynamic_image_view.xml file.

**Here is link of my output:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6TH-xS6p0y0ZTE5VFpiOUI3R2M/view?usp=sharing

**Here is my code:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewGroup ll = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_image_view,null);
    ll.addView(view.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_image));
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/ll"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.harmeet.dynamicimageloadtest.MainActivity">

</LinearLayout>
```

**dynamic_image_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:src="@drawable/images"
android:id="@+id/dynamic_image"
android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Comment: I want to set ImmageView height to 200dp but its not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Dynamically Add Views into View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view)

Comment: `ImageView's layout_height and layout_width are not set according set ImageView's layout`. sorry but I see it display correct. can you explain more

Comment: @Joshua - In that, they have given example to add TextView dynamically. I have added it dynamcially but want to set layout_height of imageView to 200dp which I have set in dynamic_image_view.xml file which is not working. Height of image is gtting set according to the height of resource image.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh -  I want to set height of ImageView to 200dp but height is set according to height of image resource.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghVirdi I still can not believe that the `height is set according to height of image resource`, can you increase `200dp` to `800dp` and tell me what will happend

Comment: Have you tried changing to `inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_image_view, parent, false);`

Comment: @PhanVănLinh - Same output again after setting to 800dp

Comment: @ShreeKrishna - your answer is correct. thanx

Comment: @HarmeetSinghVirdi you're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe problem is your inflate params-  you need to pass it the linear layout as the root if you want all the width/height/margins to correctly parse.  And that way you won't need to add it later.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_image_view,ll);
```

Comment: I tried this but app is crashing. Here is error - 
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**

Comment: That adds it for you.  Don't add it again after that

Answer (score 2):

**Change your**

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_image_view,null);
```

**TO**

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_image_view, parent, false);
```