# How to Store and Retrieve Dynamically added Elements in fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm Adding Some Elements **Dynamically**, and i'm succeed in that. Now i want to **store** them in **SQLite** or any other **database** option. Also i want to **retrieve** them too.

Here's the code of *how i'm adding elements dynamically in my fragment*.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

final TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)                                     view.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
 final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);

 FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

           number = number + 1;

           EditText text = new EditText(getActivity());
           TextView id = new TextView(getActivity());

           id.setHint(number + ". ");
           text.setHint("Enter Device Name");

           tableLayout.addView(id);
           tableLayout.addView(text);

     }
    }
});


FloatingActionButton fab_save =     (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fab_save);
fab_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        // save added elements



        // save added elements

    }
});
 }
```

I want to save my data in fab_save.

Comment: Noone can give you a tailormade solution on that, because storing data in sqlite is very project case dependant. Look at my answer to get some ideas on how to do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not save your objects directly within a database.
You should save the data of the object, like text or states into corresponding sqlite table. When you need the element again, read the data from the database and generate a new view out of that data.

See the official android developer page on how to save/store data into database (in my oppinion it's quite easy to understand that even as a newbie):
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

To generate views out of data look at this related post:
[Android - Dynamically Add Views into View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view)

Comment: can you provide some stuff that i can use to store my view's data into db as per my above code.

Comment: Spend one hour to read about the sqlite topic (see link above). You can easily modify the android developer example, i needed one hour to get familiar to that topic. It sounds cruel but without understandig it, you won't have much effort in developping apps. I know it's hard to invest time, but it's worth it and you won't run into the next trouble and bugs because you didn't understand the implementation