# How can I add programmatically TextView in included layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a `BaseLayout`, the `BaseLayout` is a `ParentLayout` for other layouts. In other words, the other Layouts inherit/include it. The `BaseLayout` has `DrawerLayout` (shared for all layouts) but each `Activity` has a different content.

**My BaseLayout looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/myDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--Main Content-->
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/rootLinearLayout"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">
      <!--Content-->

    <!--must add Other Layout elements there 
     must add Other Layout elements there 
     must add Other Layout elements there 
     must add Other Layout elements there 
     must add Other Layout elements there !-->

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Left Navigation Derawer -->
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/llLeftDrawer"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="240dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
      android:padding="15dp"
      android:layout_gravity="right">
      <!-- Left Navigation Derawer Content-->
      <TextView
        android:text="Categories"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        fontPath="fonts/MobileFont.ttf" />
      <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvLeftMenu"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**and included in `Postlayout` like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <include
    layout="@layout/BaseLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I add `PostLayout` elements into the `BaseLayout` `LinearLayout` id `rootLinearLayout`?

**`postLayout` element is this:**

```
<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
                <TextView
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txtPostTitle"
                    android:gravity="right" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txtPostDate"
                    android:gravity="right" />
                <android.webkit.WebView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/wbvPostContent" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view You may want to further search for `android dynamically add view`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Dynamically Add Views into View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bruno Bieri get [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view)  is java and i converted to xamarin:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as LayoutInflater;
View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.your_layout, null);

// fill in any details dynamically here
TextView textView = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.a_text_view);
textView.Text="your text";

// insert into main view
ViewGroup insertPoint = FindViewById<ViewGroup>(Resource.id.insert_point);
insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

and Rohan Stark solution good for Access to elements of Included Layout

tanQ Bruno Bieri and Rohan Stark,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, provide  `id` attribute to the included `Baselayout` in the `Postlayout`.

Then, you can get the `View` object from the included view by calling the following from the activity that has the `Postlayout` :-

```
View includedView = (View)findViewById(R.id.idThatYouGaveToIncludedLayout);
```

Then, you can access all `Baselayout` views from the `includedView` object and perform the operations that you require.

For example,

```
LinearLayout rootLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)includedView.findViewById(R.id.rootLinearLayout);
```

Similar to the above code, you can obtain objects of the other views of your `Baselayout`.

Comment: I need add `postLayout` elements  in to the `rootLinearLayout` of  his own layout when included from `BaseLayout`, BaseLayout only have `DrawerLayout` .but different content for each activity ,ex `PostDetailsActivity` have 2 textview and one webview. an other activity `MainActivity` have one `RecyclerView`  andother activity ... .  What I want to do all activity's layout Included `BaseLayout` after than  add element for each activity programmatically to  his own layout `rootLinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

when you add view as include, can use all view like own main layout views. find the layout as a view and add view to it. like below:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

 linearLayout1.addView(new TextView(context));
```