# Android: Possible/Smart way to setup custom list items? (Or convenient way to setup re-used layouts)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

## Overview

As UI getting more complicated -- but still some-part-repeated at the same time, the `include` view component (or `RecyclerView` with `Adapter` in java) might be the best solution.
However, since these parts are static and specific, I wonder if there's a way to build these UI in xml-only / editor-previewable style?

---

## Example

Below is a more elaborated question: I want to build a Setting Page, with items like this:
[image]

layout should be a list, filled with items -- each one has icon, text, and a arrow.

How can I do it?

On my first thought, I use `include`.

### Step 1

I build a layout for single item names `item_option_standard.xml` (below is a simplified version):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemIcon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemSubtitle" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/itemNext" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Step 2

and re-use this by putting `include` in my `ScrollView` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/optMyCash"
            layout="@layout/item_option_standard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/optHistory"
            layout="@layout/item_option_standard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/optAnnouncement"
            layout="@layout/item_option_standard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        
        <!-- and so on... -->
        
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In editor this is showed like:

[image]

### Step 3

The last step is to modify content step to step. I wrote a helper function:

```
public static void SetupOption(@NonNull View itemView, @DrawableRes int iconId, @NonNull String itemTitle, View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    ImageView iconView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemIcon);
    iconView.setImageResource(iconId);
    TextView titleView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
    titleView.setText(itemTitle);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
}
```

and use this in my `OnCreate` :

```
SetupOption(view.findViewById(R.id.optMyCash), R.drawable.ic_my_cash, getString(R.string.title_my_cash), onClickListener);
SetupOption(view.findViewById(R.id.optHistory), R.drawable.ic_history, getString(R.string.title_history), onClickListener);
SetupOption(view.findViewById(R.id.optAnnouncement), R.drawable.ic_announce, getString(R.string.title_announce), onClickListener);
// and so on...
```

### Question

Is there any alternative way to do "Step 3"? Especially, is there a chance to do that **in xml / more static / editor-previewable way?** The method beyond cannot be previewed in editor, and it's hard-to-view, hard-to-maintain (and some kind inefficient?)

Answer (score 1):

You have to dynamically add the view. and just set the tag to the view which you want to use for click event and in the click event, you will get a view and just get the tag to differentiate the click event. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view)
- If you getting `ERROR` or something wrong then please comment down below.

Comment: Can you give more details? I don't know what's the tag you mean (and why it involves click event....?)

Comment: Oh, I just understood what's your answer: **Views are required to be added denamically.** And `tag` s are your suggestion when coming up to setup listeners. However, I just want to know if the views can be setup in a easier (more static) way. As a extra information, I use `View.getId()` with `switch` in my click listener, and I can't see any bad comparing to the `tag` s -- as the latter has to be set additionally?