# How to set a list of ImageView into a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, imageview, photo

I display my JSON data into a RecyclerView. I have multiple TextView into one item and it works perfectly.

In my data, I need to fetch photos and display them into each item. I have multiple photos for one item. It starts from 6 photos to... many more.

I tried using a RecyclerView inside my first RecyclerView but as you can guess it was a bad idea (bad performance, not the good result expected and so on).

Do you have any other solution or advice that might help, please?

I found a thousand solutions how to display one picture by row but none about multiple pictures into one row.

Comment: What's your problem with using Recyclerview inside Recylerview because that is what I would use. Please post some code, your performance issue may be from somewhere else.

Comment: Kindly post your code.

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom view and add **Image views dynamically** based on no.of views required.
Use this view in the recycler view adapter **itemlayout** file.

Comment: Like here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view

Comment: Yes, like that. But the length of coding increases.

Comment: I'm gonna give it a go. Thank you for your help!