# Add TextView, when button is pushed Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, button, textview, android-linearlayout

I don't understand why it isn't just as simple as this...

```
       // Add field
    val LineLayoutInfo = findViewById<View>(R.id.LineLayoutInfo) as LinearLayout
    val Add_Field = findViewById<View>(R.id.buttonAddField) as Button
    Add_Field.setOnClickListener{

        val tv1 = TextView(this@MainActivity)
        tv1.text = "Show Up"
        val t = TextView(applicationContext)

        LineLayoutInfo.addView(tv1)
    }
```

All I want to do is create a new TextView inside my current LinearLayout. This part of the code is written in Kotlin and stored in the OnCreate(). Is it maybe because I need to refresh the activity?

The output I get when I push the button, looks like this.

```
D/HwAppInnerBoostImpl: asyncReportData com.xxx.httpposter,2,1,1,0 interval=83
I/ViewRootImpl: jank_removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
D/HwAppInnerBoostImpl: asyncReportData com.xxx.httpposter,2,1,2,0 interval=353
```

Comment: Try checking out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
private LinearLayout mLayout;
private Button mButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(onClick());
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("New text");
}

private OnClickListener onClick() {
    return new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mLayout.addView(createNewTextView("New Text"));
        }
    };
}

private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setText("New text: " + text);
    return textView;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Saylavie1997 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Okay cool, I will do that. I'm still figuring out the functions and features here on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

Here, you could just create the TextView and set it's Visibility to `INVISIBLE` on `MainActivity` after the `onCreate()` of the program, then on button click set it to `VISIBLE`. You could do this infinitely!

Comment: Yeah okay, that is a different way to think about it :) That would be a possibility.

Comment: Or, you could just `append` a `TextView` to create the illusion you know...
More like the one posted in the big CodeBlock, just have to convert it from Java to Kotlin in your case though...

Comment: Cool, but it's fine. I have it working exactly as I wanted now ;)

Comment: Ok! Goodluck on your project!