# Issue in Display view dynamically code failed

Tags: android, kotlin

I am very new to Android development and actually stuck with code in tutorial for Kotlin programming for android. The code below is not working and I have tried to find alternative but no luck.
Will appreciate if somebody can help we with the alternative code
below is a code:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        addSomeViews(count = 5)
    }

    fun addSomeViews(count: Int) {
        for (i in 1..count) {
            val textView = TextView(this)
            textView.text = "Hey, learner # $i"
            textView.textSize = 20f
            my_layout.addView(textView)
        }

        val button = Button(this)
        button.text = "Click me!"
        my_layout.addView(button)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - Dynamically Add Views into View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view)

Comment: Unable to adopt this code.
I have create liner layout. It is now not recognizing activity main. 

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_layout"
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val vi = applicationContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val v: View = vi.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null)
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

That `kotlinx.synthetic` stuff is deprecated - it doesn't work anymore. Instead of just referencing `my_layout` directly (the synthetics are supposed to look it up for you and create that variable) you need to find it yourself:

```
fun addSomeViews(count: Int) {
    // lookup the layout viewgroup and create a variable for it
    val my_layout = findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.layout.my_layout)
        for (i in 1..count) {
            val textView = TextView(this)
            textView.text = "Hey, learner # $i"
            textView.textSize = 20f
            // now this variable exists
            my_layout.addView(textView)
        }
    }
```

Aside from that... this isn't how a beginner should be learning Android imo. Creating views like this is kind of an advanced thing, mostly you never have to do it, and if you do there's a bunch of configuration you need to do on the views to make them display correctly (like the appropriate `LayoutParams`)

You *can* do it, but mostly you create your layouts in XML using the layout editor. And [Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) is the new thing for writing UI in code, which is probably worth learning. It's up to you obviously, I just wanted to warn you that it's a strange thing for a beginner to be learning, and you might be better trying the [Codelabs](https://developer.android.com/courses/fundamentals-training/toc-v2) stuff instead