# Android: remove fields which are created dynamacally

Tags: android, android-view, android-spinner

In my android application I dynamically create one  **TableRow** and I insert one textView and one editTextView in this tableRow.

there is one more filed which is spinner. Depending on the selection on spinner this TableRow is create or remove.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995215/add-and-remove-views-in-android-dynamically) they mention how to remove fields from layout but the problem is how I get the view.

Here my code is:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int pos, long id) {

            if (pos > 1) {
                tableRowName = new TableRow(this);
                tableRowName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                textViewName = new TextView(this);
                textViewName.setText("Name*");
                textViewName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                textViewName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                editTextPersonName = new EditText(this);
                editTextPersonName.setHint("Name");
                editTextPersonName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                tableRowName.addView(textViewName);
                tableRowName.addView(editTextPersonName);

                tableLayout.addView(tableRowName, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            } else {

                tableRowName.removeView((View) v.getParent());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "onNothingSelected() method is called by Stage Spinner",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

This code able to create tableRow but not able to remove this tableRow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could better have the view already added in layout xml and then set visibility to GONE or VISIBLE dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

set a tag to a view with `v.setTag("my textView");`
then when you want to find it use `findViewByTag("my textView");`

Comment: how to set a tag and where to set a tag and when I need to call findViewByTag. Please explain this in a brief.

Comment: you asked how you could find a view. when you create it set a tag to it with any name that you want, and when you have to find it again search it by it's tag. then do whatever you need (remove it from parent / make invisible)