# Dynamically hide a viewstub when a new one is created

Tags: android, view, stub, viewgroup

I made a `viewstub` that is inflated and created again many times. The layout it uses includes a "delete" button that hides the viewstub (or deflates it).

When I'm creating a new `viewstub` I call this code:

```
ViewStub eventStub = new ViewStub(this);
            eventStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.event_container);
            eventContainerMain.addView(eventStub);
            eventStub.inflate();
```

Problem is, in the `viewstub` layout the delete button is created with the new `viewstub`. So how do I make the delete button hide the `viewstub`thats inside?

Most importantly, How do I make other methods affect **only the view its inside**?

Comment: just use setVisibility(View.GONE) for delete view

Comment: Thank you, but how do I make it target the view its in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't quite using view stubs correctly...

First, point your view to the layout you desire for the view you want to duplicate by using this:

```
ViewStub stub = new ViewStub(this);
    stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.viewStubLayout);
    stub.inflate();
```

Next, go into your XML and make sure the buttons on your layout have the `android:onClick` option using the correct method, which is declared in your class.

For deleting view stubs, you don't actually delete them... you're supposed to use `.setVisibility(GONE)` or `.setVisibility(VISIBLE)` to manage if users can see it or not. This would be used in the method in which `onClick` is directed to. Also, using "`this`" when referring to the view stub your objects are in will allow you to manage what happens in the specified view the user clicks in.

Answer (score 0):

You do not delete view stubs in the way that you want them to be deleted. When inflated, ViewStubs simply disappear from the parent and are replaced with a View object. If you want to use methods on the view that is created you can use the android:inflatedId attribute in the `ViewStub` xml file.

You say that the layout you are using has a "delete" button that "deflates" the `ViewStub`, but in reality what is happening is that you are deleting the View that is created when you inflate the `ViewStub`. Once a `ViewStub` is inflated it is deleted from the parent automatically and so after inflation there wouldn't be a `Viewstub` in existence to delete.

What it sounds like you want is to dynamically delete the `View` created by the inflated ViewStub. For this I suggest looking at [Add and Remove Views in Android Dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995215/add-and-remove-views-in-android-dynamically)