# adding checkbox in customer alert dialog

Tags: android

I am trying to add checkboxes to a alertdialog screen. I am inflating the alertdialog usig a custom xml lay out. Below is the code. The alert dialog is coming up(on a button click in my main activity) with all the elements as I had defined in the xml. But I don't see checkboxes being added to the dialog view. Can any one suggest here.

```
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View uploadScreenView = factory.inflate(R.layout.uploadscreen, null);
    alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
    alert.setTitle(this.getString(R.string.AlertDialog_Message_ConfirmUpload));
    alert.setView(uploadScreenView);
    String[] itemNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories_array);  
    CheckBox[] cbs = new CheckBox[itemNames.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.length; i++) {
        //cb.add(new CheckBox(uploadQuizView.getContext()));
        cbs[i] = new CheckBox(uploadScreenView.getContext());
        cbs[i].setText(itemNames[i]);
    }
    //....alert.setpositive/negative button , show code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not "bind" your checkboxes to your view, so they are not displayed.

What you should do is something like that:

```
 CheckBox[] cbs = new CheckBox[itemNames.length]; 
 for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.length; i++) 
 {
        cbs[i] = new CheckBox(uploadScreenView.getContext());
        cbs[i].setText(itemNames[i]);
        uploadScreenView.addView(cbs[i]);
 }
```

The key of this code is the `addView` method. You can check out its [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995215/add-and-remove-views-in-android-dynamically).

Comment: addView is not showing against uploadScreenView. I had tried that before posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

Updated working code below. I changed uploadScreenView from View to ViewGroup. Child cannot be added to the a view without any parent(Layout or Viewgroup defined)

```
 LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final ViewGroup uploadScreenView = factory.inflate(R.layout.uploadscreen, null);
alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
alert.setTitle(this.getString(R.string.AlertDialog_Message_ConfirmUpload));
alert.setView(uploadScreenView);
String[] itemNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories_array);  
CheckBox[] cbs = new CheckBox[itemNames.length]; 
for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.length; i++) {
           cbs[i] = new CheckBox(uploadScreenView.getContext());
    cbs[i].setText(itemNames[i]);
     uploadScreenView .addView(cbs[i]);
}
//....alert.setpositive/negative button , show code here
```