# setContentView() with XML layout vs View

Tags: java, android

In Android, I'm used to setting layouts with the XML file

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

But you can also set the content using a View in Java

```
    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
```

This has the side effect of not being able to use the layout file any more.

Is there anyway I can programatically set, for example, a text value and still use the layout.xml file?

Comment: Well, I don't think you can apply both to setContentView() in one Activity.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995215/add-and-remove-views-in-android-dynamically or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203506/how-can-i-add-a-textview-to-a-linearlayout-dynamically-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.

In your **layout.xml** file  you must define an `id` of the `main layout` `(android:id="@+id/mainLayout" )` and then you can do this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewGroup mainView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    mainView.addView(textView);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use setContentView(R.layout.activity_main), you are telling that the layout to be used is the xml layout file activity_main.

When you use setContentView(textView), it **replaces** the previous added xml layout file by the textView component.

You can declare your TextView in the layout file and then set the text programmatically.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);
```

Answer (score -1):

for example:

in layout.xml paste this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/lblText"
        android:textSize="40"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and, in you MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    private TextView lblText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.lblText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblText);
        this.lblText.setText("your message");        
    }
}
```