# removeViewAt does not work

Tags: java, android, button, view, android-relativelayout

I got a RelativeLayout and I'm trying to remove a view from it. I tried removeViewAt and removeView but the view is still there even after I call them. Do you guys know what could be wrong?

```
RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
Button btn = new Button(this);
v.addView(btn);
v.removeView(btn);
```

Comment: actually that should work, did you try v.removeAllViews(); ?

Comment: You can't do it directly. Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995215/add-and-remove-views-in-android-dynamically

Comment: Can you try: ((ViewGroup)btn.getParent()).removeView(btn);

Comment: I tried the getParent() thing but it did not work :(