# How to remove a ImageView inside of LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

In my app, I select photos from gallery and insert them inside of `LinearLayout` programmatically, so I did this :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearImages"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp">
            <Button
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/add_btn"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/add_icon"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

And i'm set a tag to which photo that I'm putting :

```
public void AddNewImages(Context context,Bitmap bitmap){
    ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
    img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    img.setTag(tagCount);
    linearImages.addView(img);
    bitmapArray.add(bitmap);
    tagCount++;
}
```

And I want to remove a Image by tapping, as I said before, the Images are added programmatically, so I need something to remove images one by one without have a static Image position.

Comment: This link may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995215/add-and-remove-views-in-android-dynamically

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use `RecyclerView` instaed of `LinearLayout`. The reason being you can easily get the position of the item clicked and can remove accordingly. If you want to go with your own solution, then I would suggest to add `setOclickListener` on each `ImageView` being added. In the listener after the click event get the `imagView.getTag()`, which is the position of the image view within `LinearLayout`. You can then remove the image view from the `LinearLayout` by using:

```
ll.removeViewAt(position);// to remove view from particular position
```

Or if you want to remove `ImageView` being clicked directly then:

```
ll.removeView(view)// to remove particular view
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code of AddNewImages It will work.

```
public void AddNewImages(Context context,Bitmap bitmap){
        ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
        img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        img.setTag(tagCount);
        linearImages.addView(img);
        bitmapArray.add(bitmap);
        tagCount++;
        img.setOnClickListener(clickListner);
        View.OnClickListener clickListner=new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                linearImages.removeView(v);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: So this `ImageView  img= (ImageView) v;` would be for what?

Comment: It is not required . you can directly call linearImages.removeView(v).

Comment: It works, at the first, but if I try to add again, i got this Exception "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Comment: It is not possible Your are creating a new Instance of ImageView and By default it has not parent so how you get such exception.