# Inflate one layout multiple times during runtime within a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

**Is it possible to inflate and remove a layout multiple times within another layout. I have a main layout as below**

tab_bar.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:paddingLeft="8dip"
  android:paddingRight="12dip"
  android:paddingTop="2dip"
  android:paddingBottom="1dip"
  android:background="@drawable/search_plate_browser" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      >
      <ImageButton android:id="@+id/arrow_left"
         android:background="@drawable/ic_back"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="30dip"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:visibility="gone"
      />
      <ImageButton android:id="@+id/arrow_right"
         android:background="@drawable/ic_forward"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="30dip"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:visibility="gone"
       />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/addtab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="4dip"
    android:paddingRight="4dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:paddingBottom="4dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background ="@drawable/tabicon"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Inside this layout i need to add and remove the below tab layout dynamically on click of some button**

tabview.xml

```
  <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="220dip"
         android:layout_height="35dip"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:background="@drawable/browsertab_add">
      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/favicon"
         android:layout_width="15dip"
         android:layout_height="15dip"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
         android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
         android:layout_marginRight="2dip" 
         android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"/>
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/title"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_width="140dip"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
         android:textColor="@color/white"
         android:scrollHorizontally="true"
         android:lines="1"
         android:singleLine="true" />
      <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/close"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
         android:gravity="left"
         android:background="@drawable/ic_tab_close" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions on this would be great..

Answer (score 2):

Do not remove it just simply set its visibility to Gone :)

Some links on the subject:

[Android, add new view without XML Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211559/android-add-new-view-without-xml-layout)

[Android Runtime Layout Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693744/android-runtime-layout-tutorial)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Comment: Although you can also remove them

Answer (score 1):

Yes I Think you can inflate one layout in another e.g. I add views to my ViewFlipper multiple times. And these views are basically a Layout that I inflate and then add as a child. Here is the example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout ll_main = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabview,null);
```

Now you have grabbed the LinearLayout as "ll_main" and now you can add it to the required Layout as a child.